# Prove that the logarithm of the absolute value has Fourier's transformation

Tags: fourier-analysis, indefinite-integrals, fourier-transform

Let $f$ be the function:

$$
f(t) = \begin{cases} \log{\left| t\right|} \quad 0<\left| t\right| \le 1\\  0 \quad\quad\quad \left|t\right| > 1 \end{cases}
$$

I have to prove that it admits the Fourier's transformation of type

$$
\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}{f(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,\mathrm{dt}}
$$

And my notes says that it is sufficient if I prove that $f$ is absolutely integrable, but I can't find an easy way of proving that

$$
\int_{-1}^{0}{\left| \log{(-t)}\right| \mathrm{dt}} + \int_{0}^{1}{\left| \log{t}\right| \mathrm{dt}} \,<\, \pm\infty
$$

I would appreciate any clue or method for solving this, thanks.

Comment: Replace $0$ with $\epsilon>0$ and take limits as $\epsilon\to 0$.